# wicket components - publisher - subcriber pattern

Tags: jakarta-ee, wicket

publisher - subcriber pattern is a very well knowen one 
I want to know if there is an interface of wicket to be using this pattern

my goal is

lets say someone add item to shopping cart then the sum component draw itself couse it subscribed to the event published by the cart component ad draw itself

is there somthing in the wicket inferstractuare I can use ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/atmosphere/EventBus.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use Wicket's built-in event mechanism - please see the corresponding [example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/events/) to see if it suits your needs.

Comment: I wish I'd been aware of this 3 months ago!